# Null Pointer Exception with Unknown source (Ud.f)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have an App published in google app store and i get strange `log` about a crash from an unknown source.

This happens on devices like Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 Pro (whyred), 3840MB RAM, Android 9.

I try to find the same issue reported anywhere but i couldn't.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException:


    at com.baruchi.simpletime.main.Ud.f (Unknown Source:43)
    at b.j.a.h.k (Unknown Source)
    at b.j.a.v.m (Unknown Source:13)
    at b.j.a.v.w (Unknown Source:77)
    at b.j.a.h.k (Unknown Source:7)
    at b.j.a.v.m (Unknown Source:13)
    at b.j.a.v.w (Unknown Source:77)
    at b.j.a.m.m (Unknown Source:4)
    at b.j.a.k.onSaveInstanceState (Unknown Source:8)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.m.onSaveInstanceState (Unknown Source)
    at com.baruchi.simpletime.main.MainActivity.onSaveInstanceState (Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState (Activity.java:1599)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState (Instrumentation.java:1444)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState (ActivityThread.java:4872)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnStop (ActivityThread.java:4214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSleeping (ActivityThread.java:4340)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400 (ActivityThread.java:200)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1772)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Comment: You are getting a crash from unknown source as you must have Proguard enabled on your app. You can check for mappings.txt file to identify which class is renamed to "Ud" by proguard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As NIKHIL AGGARWAL said, the application renamed (obfuscated) classes and methods with Proguard (or R8). You should have `mapping.txt` to deobfuscate these names.

So, checkout the release branch (that commit after that you released the application). Then generate signed aab or apk. In `app\build\outputs\mapping\release` you will see `resources.txt` and `mapping.txt` files. Save them to another folder. You can manually see, what happens in `mapping.txt`. Load this file to your analytics system where you see crash logs.